# Using DIR for files in subdirectories

Tags: command

I have the following directory structure:

```
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.01
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.01\Files
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.01\Files\1
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.01\Files\2
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.01\Files\3
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.02
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.02\Files
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.02\Files\3
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.03
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.04
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.04\Files
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.04\Files\2
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.04\Files\3
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.05
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.05\Files
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.05\Files\1
C:\Users\me\data\2017.01.05\Files\3
```

That's a subset - I have folders for every day last year and this year. Each day's folder may or may not have have a Files directory; each Files directory may or may not have subdirectories 1, 2, and/or 3 (note that in the above all of the incidents of '1', '2', or '3' are directories, not files. - they may or may not have files in them).

What I'm after is a windows command prompt command (dir ?) which will list all the files in all of the directories named '1'. I've tried things like:

```
dir \s *\files
dir \s *\files\*
```

but can't get anything to work.

Can it be done?

FYI - Windows 10, 64 bit.

Comment: Type `dir /?` at a command prompt. The switch operator on Windows is */*, not *\*. Wildcards are not supported before directories, so you can't use `*\files`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done in a single command, but you can pipe commands together, and so combine "dir" with "find".  Try the following :

```
dir /s /b | find "\1\"
```

Answer (score -1):

go to the directory you want to start at. Type "tree". This will give you a representation of the file structure

Comment: That's not what the question asked.